# How to vibrate BlackBerry though code?(Java)

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, vibration

Here is what I'm trying to do ..
Whenever event occurs, device should vibrate for couple of seconds.

I tried to use 

`Display.getDisplay(this).vibrate(2000);`

It did not vibrate, while testing on device
Even tried it with device profile was set to Vibrate(Active)

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Alert.isVibrateSupported()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html#isVibrateSupported()), [Alert.startVibrate(time)](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html#startVibrate(int)) and [Alert.stopVibrate()](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/Alert.html#stopVibrate())